# Swift 5.5 Await Async Mocking and Unit Tests - Alamofire

Tags: swift, unit-testing, async-await

Lets say I have something like this

```swift
import Alamofire

class NetworkStuff {
    
    func getSomething() async throws -> String {
        let params: [String: String] = ["Key": "Value"]
    
        let value = AF.request("https://myapi.com/endpoint", method: .post, parameters:  params, encoder: JSONParameterEncoder.default)
            .validate()
            .responseDecodable([String: String].self).value("KeyIWant")
        guard let result = value else {throw MyError.SomeError }
        return result
    }
}
```

How would I go about writing a unit test to validate that this request is right and that im decoding the response.
Lets say we send this to the server:

```
{
"RequestItem": "Value"
}
```

Lets say the response from the server looks like:

```
{
  "ID": "1234",
  "KeyIWant": "Value02"
}
```

How could I write a test to ensure my POST parameters were structured correctly as the server expects and then mock a response so that I ensure im parsing this correctly to get the value I want?

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind that you do not want to test the network or AlamoFire or the server at the endpoint. You want to test only *your* code.

To do that, you need to make your code testable. Break out `getSomething` into subroutines that are testable — this sort of thing:

```
func getSomething() async throws -> String {
    let params = self.constructParams()
    let value = AF.request("https://myapi.com/endpoint", method: .post, parameters:  params, encoder: JSONParameterEncoder.default)
    let result = self.processValue(value)
    return result
}
```

Now `constructParams` and `processValue` are methods that you can test by normal means, providing various inputs and checking to see that you get back the expected outputs.

Answer (score -1):

I will break the answer into two parts (I assume you are familiar with XCTest framework or its open-source wrappers, Quick and Nimble, those are my recommendation to be used for testing):

First, writing a test to make sure the POST parameters are structured correctly - I would reconstruct the function and pass them as an argument to it. Then I would write a class that is in charge of building the parameters and write a testing suite for it - making sure it builds the parameters correctly, something like

```
final class ParamBuilder {
  func params() -> [String: Any] { ["Key": "Value"] }
}

// Testing
class ParamBuildierTests: XCTestCase {

  func testFirst() {
      let builder = ParamBuilder()
       XCTAssertEqual(builder.params(), ["Key": "Value"])
  }
}
```

Second, mock and test response.
I personally recommend using [Mockingjay](https://github.com/kylef/Mockingjay) Its usage is pretty straightforward, and it can mock response such that you can keep using the same service `NetworkStuff`  which is using Alamofire (URLSession underlying). It will stub the response according to your preference - you can mock 404 response and different payloads